# How to get the code of the line currently running in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to write a function in JavaScript, it needs to get the string form (text in source code) of its parameter instead of the value of the parameter.

**Note: The type of the parameter may be anything, not restricted to be of string, and the value of the parameter may be any expression.**

For example:

```
function processParam(param)
{
    let literalCode = ""; 
    ...
}

// I want to get the string "100 * 2" instead of 200 inside this function.
processParam(100 * 2); 


// I want to get the string "console.log('abc')" instead of undefined inside this function.
processParam(console.log('abc'));
```

In other words, I want to get the code of the line that is currently running. How can I do this?

Comment: That's impossible. `100 * 2` has already been evaluated *before* the function is called.

Comment: Can you provide more context? Why do you need this? What are you trying to build?

Comment: @felix-kling I want to write a tool to log an expression and its result, so I needs to get the literal code of expressions.

Comment: And where does the expression come from? And what kind of expressions are we talking about? Math? Arbitrary JavaScript? If the expression is user provided then you will most likely receive it as a string anyways. Then the challenge would be to evaluate that expression.

Answer (score 1):

That is not really possible like that. But with a slight change you can get some source code. Functions have source code. So if you pass the argument as a function, you can get the source code. And if you want the actual value, you should execute it.

Here is a demo:

```js
function processParam(param){
    let literalCode = param.toString().split("=>").pop().trim();
    console.log(literalCode);
    let actualValue = param(); // execute it
}

processParam(() =>100 * 2); 
processParam(() => console.log('abc'));
```